# How do I use Sublime Text as the OS editor in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, ruby, gem

How do I set Sublime Text as the editor for git commits in Mac OS X?

In my .zshrc I have:

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

But, if I do:

```
bundle open devise
```

I get the error:

```
Could not run 'subl -w /Users/edwardandrews-hodgson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@neighbours/gems/devise-2.1.3'
```

How should I reference Sublime?

Comment: Can you launch Sublime Text by running `subl -w` manually?

Comment: if the subl executable is not in your path, try using the full path in the editor environment variable

Comment: ...or add the path to where the `subl` command is living.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you'll need to create a soft link to the `subl` command. If you haven't already, create a personal `bin` directory:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

then create the soft link:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Next, open your `.zshrc` and add the following to the end:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Now restart Terminal.app (or whichever term program you're using) and you should be able to open any file in ST2 from the command line using the `subl` command. Since your `$EDITOR` variable is already set properly, `bundle open devise` should work as expected. Keep in mind that if you have the MacPorts version of Python installed, you'll need to open Sublime Text 2.app from the Finder before the command line `subl` command will work.

Comment: Fantastic - that was more complicated than I thought it would be!